# 404 not found . hekp me to solve this

Tags: github-pages

I made my own page in github but it doesn’t open it's only showing 404 not found. All this for coursera HTML, CSS, Java Script course.
https://felixking554.github.io/coursera-test/site/
Here's my page

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The default Jekyll configuration would generate a site in `_site`, not [`site`](https://github.com/Felixking554/coursera-test/blob/gh-pages/site/index.html).

Try and set in `config.yml` your `destination         : ./site`, and see if the `site/` folder would be now recognized as GitHub pages.

If not, try and follow [the documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/), like this [step by step tutorial](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/creating-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll).

Comment: I tried but it's still doesn't work

Comment: @RitamDebnath I thought it did work since you accepted the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn’t check it before

Comment: @RitamDebnath I would recommend following https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/creating-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll for testing. I have edited the answer.

Comment: I'm sure my code is right but it doesn't work when it comes to github page

Comment: <title>Hello Coursera!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello Coursera!</h1>
<h1>Hello Coursera! It's a great course!</h1>
</body>
</html>

Comment: that's my code.

Comment: @RitamDebnath Exactly, which is why I would recommend following a tutorial, just to make GitHub pages work, and then adapt the example to inject back your own code.

Comment: ok I'll try it.